# Ajax filters displays all data but does not filter. DJANGO AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

i'm using ajax filtering to filter my products by color, brand, size. The data filtering successfully but it shows everything. I'm hoping for your help and thank you for your attention

```
Trying to filter products...
product-filter.js:20 {data: '\n\n    \n        <div class="col-md-4 mb-0">\n       …   </div>\n            </div>\n        </div>\n    \n'}data: "\n\n    \n        <div class=\"col-md-4 mb-0\">\n[[Prototype]]: Object
product-filter.js:21 Data filtered successfully
```

ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".filter-checkbox").on('click', function(){
        let filter_object = {};
        $(".filter-checkbox").each(function(index,ele){
            let filter_value = $(this). val();
            let filter_key=$(this). data('filter');
            filter_object[filter_key]=Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[data-filter='+filter_key+']:checked')).map(function(element){
                return element.value;
            });
        });

        $.ajax({
            url:'/filter_products',
            data:filter_object,
            dataType:'json',
            beforeSend:function(){
                console.log('Trying to filter products...');
            },
            success:function(response){
                console.log(response);
                console.log('Data filtered successfully');
                $("filteredProducts").html(response.data)

            }
        });
    });
});
```

views.py

```
def filter_products(request):
    color = request.GET.getlist('color[]')
    brand = request.GET.getlist('brand[]')
    size = request.GET.getlist('size[]')
    products = Product.objects.all().order_by('-id').distinct()
    if len(color)>0:
        products=products.filter(color__id__in=color).distinct()
    if len(brand)>0:
        products=products.filter(brand__id__in=brand).distinct()
    if len(size)>0:
        products=products.filter(size__id__in=size).distinct()
    t = render_to_string('ajax/product-list.html',{'products':products})
    return JsonResponse({'data':t})


def search(request):
    data1 = wishData(request)
    wishItems = data1['wishItems']

    data = cartData(request)
    q = request.GET['q']
    cartItems = data['cartItems']


    products = Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=q).order_by('id')

    context = {'products': products, 'cartItems': cartItems,'wishItems': wishItems}
    return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)




def product_view(request, id):
    product = Product.objects.filter(id=id).first()

    data = cartData(request)
    cartItems = data['cartItems']

    data1 = wishData(request)
    wishItems = data1['wishItems']

    context = {'product':product, 'cartItems':cartItems, 'wishItems':wishItems}

    return render(request, 'store/product_view.html', context)



def store(request):
    data1 = wishData(request)
    wishItems = data1['wishItems']

    data = cartData(request)

    cartItems = data['cartItems']


    products = Product.objects.all()

    color = Color.objects.all()
    size = Size.objects.all()
    brand = Brand.objects.all()
    price = Product.objects.values_list('price')

    context = {'products':products, 'cartItems':cartItems, 'wishItems':wishItems,'color':color, 'size':size, 'brand':brand, 'price':price}
    return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.store, name="store"),
    path('cart/', views.cart, name="cart"),
    path('checkout/', views.checkout, name="checkout"),
    path('login/', views.loginPage, name="login"),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name="logout"),
    path('registration/', views.registrationPage, name="registration"),
    path('profile/', views.profile, name="profile"),
    path('change_password/', PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='store/change_password.html', success_url='profile', form_class=PasswordUpdateForm ), name="change_password"),
    path('change_password/profile/', views.profile, name="profile"),

    path('filter_products/', views.filter_products, name="filter_products"),
    path('update_item/', views.updateItem, name="update_item"),
    path('update_wish_item/', views.updateWishItem, name="update_wish_item"),
    path('process_order/', views.processOrder, name="process_order"),
    path('wishlist/', views.wishlist, name="wishlist"),
    path('search/', views.search, name="search"),
    path('<int:id>', views.product_view, name="product_view"),
    path('search/<int:id>',views.product_view, name="product_view"),

]
```

product-list.html

```
    {% for product in products %}
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-0">
            <div class="card" style="width: 17rem; margin:40px;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{product.imageURL}}" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><strong>{{product.name}}</strong></h5>
                    <button data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-dark add-btn update-cart" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="top" >Add to Cart</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="{{product.id}}">View</a>
                    <button data-product={{product.id}} data-action="add"  data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off" class="btn btn-outline-danger add-btn update-wishlist" style="margin-left:19px;">♡</button>
                    <h4 style="display: inline-block; float: right"><strong>{{product.price}} ₽</strong></h4>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

filters.html

```
{% load static %}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/product-filter.js' %}"></script>
            <h3 class="mb-4 border-bottom pb-4">Filters</h3>
            <!-- Price Filter -->
            <div class="card mb-10" style="margin-top:50px;">
                <h6 class="card-header">Price</h6>
                <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <input type="range" value="{{minMaxPrice.price__min}}" max={{minMaxPrice.price__max}} min={{minMaxPrice.price__min}} id="rangeInput" oninput="maxPrice.value=this.value" />
                        <p>{{minMaxPrice.price__min}}-{{minMaxPrice.price__max}}</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        Max: <input type="number" value="{{minMaxPrice.price__min}}" max={{minMaxPrice.price__max}} min={{minMaxPrice.price__min}} class="form-control" id="maxPrice" onkeyup="rangeInput.value=this.value" id="maxPrice" />
                        <button id="priceFilterBtn" class="btn btn-info btn-sm mt-1">Filter</button>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Filter 1 -->
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <h6 class="card-header">Colors</h6>
                <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    {% for colors in color %}
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <input class="filter-checkbox" data-filter="color" value="{{colors.id}}" type="checkbox" />&nbsp;
                        <button class="btn" style="background-color: {{colors.color_code}}; margin-top: -5px;box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 ;"></button>
                        {{colors.title}}
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card mb-4">
                <h6 class="card-header">Brands</h6>
                <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    {% for brands in brand %}
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <input class="filter-checkbox" data-filter="brand" value="{{brands.id}}" type="checkbox" />&nbsp;
                        {{brands.title}}
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Filter 3 -->
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <h6 class="card-header">Sizes</h6>
                <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    {% for sizes in size %}
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <input class="filter-checkbox" data-filter="size" value="{{sizes.id}}" type="checkbox" />&nbsp;
                        {{sizes.title}}
                    </li>
                    {%endfor%}
                </div>
            </div>
```

store.html

```
{% extends 'store/main.html' %}
{%load static%}
{% block content %}
<main class="container my-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" >
            {% include 'store/filters.html' %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <!-- Products -->
            <h3 class="mb-9 border-bottom pb-4" style="margin-left:40px;">
                Products
            </h3>
            <div class="row" id="filteredProducts">
                {% for product in products %}
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-0">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 17rem; margin:40px;">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{product.imageURL}}" alt="Card image cap">
                              <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title"><strong>{{product.name}}</strong></h5>
                                <button data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-dark add-btn update-cart" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="top" >Add to Cart</button>
                                <a class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="{{product.id}}">View</a>
                                <button data-product={{product.id}} data-action="add"  data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off" class="btn btn-outline-danger add-btn update-wishlist" style="margin-left:19px;">♡</button>
                                <h4 style="display: inline-block; float: right"><strong>{{product.price}} ₽</strong></h4>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
{% endblock %}
```

and some models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    gender_choices = [('Male', 'Male'), ('Female', 'Female')]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    detail = models.TextField()
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=gender_choices, default='Male')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True,null=False, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url

class Brand(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url

class Size(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Color(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    color_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

i want to filter my products by several parameters at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed part of your jQuery selector.  It's an element with an ID so you need to preceed it with # -
Try:

```
$("#filteredProducts").html(response.data)
```